# Angular providers - I get the same result no matter if I use them or not?

Tags: angular

I'm currently learning Angular from a video course and right now I'm getting into services.

I have a demo app, with this service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoggingService {

constructor() { }

logStatusChange(status: String)
{
  console.log("A server status changed, new status:" + status);
}
}
```

and a component which looks like this:

```
.ts

import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import {LoggingService} from "../logging.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-account',
  templateUrl: './new-account.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-account.component.css']
  // providers: [LoggingService]
})
export class NewAccountComponent {
  @Output() accountAdded = new EventEmitter<{name: string, status: string}>();

  constructor(private serviceLogger: LoggingService) {};

  onCreateAccount(accountName: string, accountStatus: string) {
    this.accountAdded.emit({
      name: accountName,
      status: accountStatus
    });
    this.serviceLogger.logStatusChange(accountStatus);
  }
}

.html

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Account Name</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        #accountName>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control" #status>
        <option value="active">Active</option>
        <option value="inactive">Inactive</option>
        <option value="hidden">Hidden</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <button
      class="btn btn-primary"
      (click)="onCreateAccount(accountName.value, status.value)">
      Add Account
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I commented out the providers array because my app works the same with or without it and I can't understand why.

I'm not sure why I need to declare that providers array.
I thought it helps Angular create this value here:

```
constructor(private serviceLogger: LoggingService) {};
```

but actually it does not. (because my app works exactly the same with or without the providers array)

Can anybody help me understand why does my app behave the same and why do I need the providers array?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is this:

```js
providedIn: 'root'
```

Around Angular 6 this started being the preferred method for providing singleton services.  This automatically registers the service for you in the root injector.  You only need to specify it in a `providers` array in your module or component if this is not specified.

[angular dependency injection docs](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection)

I recommend going through the docs if you need a better understanding, there is a lot to explain and you probably don't care about most of it at this point.  There is a hierarchy of injectors going from root->module->component.

I setup an example [on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cbncxo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts):

- MyService does not use 'providedIn', so it must be declared in the providers array at some level (module/component)
- The single module, AppModule, has a providers array with MyService listed.  This means any child components in the module have access to a single instance MyService for dependency injection because a new instance of MyService is only created for that module when needed.
- ComponentA and ComponentC do not have a providers array.  When they request MyService in their constructors, Angular searches up the dependency injection tree and finds it provided for in AppModule, so they use that instance.
- ComponentB *does* have a providers array.  When it is requested in ComponentB's constructor, Angular again walks up the tree from Component->Module->Root, but it sees the service provided in the component's injector so it doesn't bother even checking the module or root injectors.  So each time ComponentB is created, a new instance of MyService is created and used.

MyService:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

let INSTANCE_NUMBER = 0;

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  instanceNumber: number;

  constructor() {
    INSTANCE_NUMBER++;
    this.instanceNumber = INSTANCE_NUMBER;
  }
}
```

The components each simply show a message with instanceNumber from their MyService instances.  You can see that there are 5 of each component.  All ten instances of ComponentA and ComponentC share instance '1' of MyService.  Each ComponentB has a separate instance of MyService, '2' through '6'.

Using 'providedIn' in the service is easier.  Generally you shouldn't be storing state in your services and don't need separate instances so having one instance for your whole app is fine.  *If* you ever did need to configure a service differently for a certain module or component, you could list it and do that configuration in the providers array of the module or componet.

Comment: I understand. Is it a good practice to also use a providers array inside my app, even if I have this providedIn property in the service? Also, what would happen if I also wouldn't have providedIn in my service?

Comment: @JohnSmith, if you use "provideI+

Comment: @JohnSmith It's best practice to use `providedIn` and to not bother with the providers[] array in either your module or component.  I've updated my answer with some more explanation, but I don't think I've had an occasion where the root injector wouldn't work and I needed to specify the service in the providers array of a module or component.

Comment: In conclusion - if I don't use providedIn/the providers array, each time this line will get executed "constructor(public myService: MyService) {};" will create another instance of myService (so it will act more like a model rather than a service), while if I do use providedIn/providers array Angular will know that it is a service and will not create another instance each time. That's why ComponentA & ComponentC output only one (they create a new instance each time). Am I right?

Comment: Really need to read through the docs to understand it, for instance child components will use their parent components' injectors if they have a providers array: [blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sl2srw?file=src%2Fapp%2Finstance.component.ts).  And you can have optional services that will be provided 'null' without an error if there are no providers in the hierarchy.

Comment: It will create a new instance for every component instance only if you use the component providers array Check out [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2ru7nn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts). Now I have a child module that provides MyService using another class OtherService that starts counting at 1000. Since app module imports it, it provides that to the components in AppModule as well. Only ComponentB uses the original MyService because it lists it in it's own providers array, and each instance of the component will get a new instance of the service.